How to insert data in a MongoDB collection with validator using Java?
I create a MongoDB collection with a validator.
db.createCollection("Student", {
    validator: { $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "Object",
        required: ["name", "score"],
        properties: {
            name: {
                bsonType: "string",
            },
            score: {
                bsonType: "object",
                required: ["History", "Math", "Computer"],
                properties: {
                    History: {
                        bsonType: "int"
                    },
                    Math: {
                        bsonType: "int"
                    },
                    Computer: {
                        bsonType: "int"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
})

I want to insert this json.
{
    "name": "scofield",
    "score":{
        "History": 45,
        "Math": 89,
        "Computer": 100
    }
}

by this code
mport org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class Add {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // link MongoDB
    MongoClient  mongoClient=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    System.out.println("client");
        
    // get MongoDatabase object
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("experiment");
        System.out.println("database");
        
        // get MongoCollection object
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Student");
        System.out.println("collection");
        
        Document studentDoc = new Document("name", "scofield")
                .append("score", new Document("History", 45)
                                    .append("Math", 89)
                                    .append("Computer", 100));
        System.out.println("create doc");
        
        collection.insertOne(studentDoc);
        System.out.println("insert");
        
        mongoClient.close();
        System.out.println("close");
    }
}

but get this error:
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
client
database
collection
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:10}] to localhost:27017
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 4, 22]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=592516}
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:11}] to localhost:27017
create doc
insert
Nov 20, 2024 4:42:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:11}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
close

Even when I change the collection without validator, I get the same error.
Then I simplify the data, and just input a key-value to collection at previous line, and get the same error
MongoDB version: 4.4.22
mongo-java-driver version: 3.2.2
I read the official documents and searched on google but found no solution yet.

It would really help us out, if you actually print the values of your insert, or other commands, instead of printing the literal strings.
